# How to configure transaction without web.xml in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions, transactional

I use Spring MVC without web.xml because I use last Spring Security config so I have a MvcConfig class like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.atoutjeu")
public class MvcConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {


    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ResourceBundle dbBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("database");
        dbBundle.getString("db.ip");
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new TransactionalDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://"+dbBundle.getString("db.ip")+":5432/"+dbBundle.getString("db.dbname"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(dbBundle.getString("db.user"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(dbBundle.getString("db.password"));  
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }


    @Bean(name="txManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "resourceBundleViewResolver")
    public ResourceBundleViewResolver getResourceBundleViewResolver(){
        ResourceBundleViewResolver rbvr = new ResourceBundleViewResolver();
        rbvr.setOrder(0);
        rbvr.setBasename("views");
        return rbvr;
    }

    @Bean
    public PretServiceImpl pretServiceImpl() {
        // configure and return a class having @Transactional methods
        return new PretServiceImpl();
    }


}
```

And I have a service :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PretServiceImpl implements IPretService {

    @Autowired
    private IAdherentDao adherentDao;

    @Autowired
    private IJeuDao jeuDao;

    @Autowired
    private IPretDao pretDao;

    @Autowired
    private IOperationDao operationDao;

    @Autowired
    private IParamLudoDao paramLudoDao;


    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AdherentServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    public int louerPaiementDirect(int idAdherent, int idJeu, String dateSortie, String dateRetourPrevue, String commentaireSortie) throws ExceptionMetier, ExceptionTechnique {
        Adherent adherent = null;
        try {
            adherent = adherentDao.getAdherent(idAdherent);
        } catch (ExceptionTechnique e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        Jeu jeu = jeuDao.getJeu(idJeu);
        Pret pret = new Pret();
        pret.setAdherent(adherent);
        pret.setJeu(jeu);
        pret.setDateSortie(DateUtils.getDateFromDatePicker(dateSortie));
        pret.setDateRetourPrevue(DateUtils.getDateFromDatePicker(dateRetourPrevue));

        pret.setCommentaireSortie(commentaireSortie);
        int idPret = pretDao.creerPret(pret);

        //throw new RuntimeException();

        //TODO créer une opération
        Operation operation = new Operation();
        operation.setAdherent(adherent);
        operation.setDateOperation(DateUtils.getDateFromDatePicker(dateSortie));
        operation.setDateReglement(DateUtils.getDateFromDatePicker(dateSortie));
        operation.setModeReglement(paramLudoDao.getParamLudo(ModeReglement.class, "mode_reglement", ModeReglement.TIRELIRE));
        operation.setPrestation(jeu.getCategorie().getPrestation());
        operation.setMontant(operation.getPrestation().getCout());
        operation.setCredit(false);
        //operation.setTauxRemise(tauxRemise);
        operationDao.creerOperation(operation);

        adherent.setTirelire(adherent.getTirelire() - jeu.getCategorie().getPrestation().getCout());
        return idPret;
    }
//....

}
```

When an exception appear my methode louerPaiementDirect doesn't roll back. I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it unchecked exception (RuntimeException or it subtype) or checked one.

Spring Framework's @transaction  rollback only in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions. You can though get rollback for checked exception with some change in your config.

Comment: I do :  throw new RuntimeException();
So it is an unchecked exception, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code for web.xml alternative

```
package com.candidjava.spring.configuration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import com.candidjava.spring.configuration.SpringConfiguration;
public class SpringWebIntializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(SpringConfiguration.class);
        context.setServletContext(container);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Refer [Spring mvc hello world example](http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/Spring-mvc-hello-world-example.htm)